# Check repeat objects in Parse.com with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, nosql

I would like to know if exist any way to check in a Parse.com database a repeat object, for example, I have this function:

```
             $scope.addRecoDeseo = function(){

                        var DeseoObjeto = new DeseoModel();

                        DeseoObjeto.set("User",Parse.User.current());
                        DeseoObjeto.set("Deseo",$scope.recomendado);

                        DeseoObjeto.save(null, {
                                  success: function(obj) {
                                        alert('ok')
                                  },
                                  error: function(obj,error) {
                                    alert("error")

                                  }
                                });

            }
```

are there any way to have a error if exist a object with the same User and Deseo?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudCode to implement a unique field, check the answer here: [Parse.com post](https://parse.com/questions/unique-fields--2)